# ObjectAnimator from left off screen clears image that will be covered up

Tags: android, objectanimator

The ObjectAnimator below works great.

```
screenWidth = 800;
ObjectAnimator moveOver =
            ObjectAnimator.ofInt(localMovingView, "left", screenWidth, 0)
                    .setDuration(500);
moveOver.start();
```

But if I change screenWidth to move in from the left, it works badly.  When the animation starts, the View that was there before the animation started instantly disappears.  The new view covers up the empty space by the end of the animation.  Both the new and old views are ViewGroups that have been added to a different ViewGroup

```
screenWidth = -800;
ObjectAnimator moveOver =
            ObjectAnimator.ofInt(localMovingView, "left", screenWidth, 0)
                    .setDuration(500);
moveOver.start();
```

I can't find anything on SO that addresses this, so help would sure be appreciated.  I have checked the disappearing view.  It has mLeft = 0;

Comment: Are you applying moveRight to the view that disappears, or only the new view?

Comment: I am applying the ObjectAnimator only to the new view that is moving onto the screen.  The prior view should stay on the screen until the animation is finished, at which point the old view will be completely covered over..

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: What about if you apply the animation to translationX instead of left?

Comment: I have a feeling, by setting the value of left, the view still extends all the way to the right side, covering the old view.

Comment: Thank you.  It might be the answer.  I'm digging into it.

Comment: @FletcherJohns   You are the best.  I've fought this forever and you fixed it in minutes.

Comment: No worries, glad it was so simple :)

Comment: WHy don't you make your answer an "answer" instead of a comment so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animating the position of Views, it is best to adjust the properties translationX and translationY. These properties are not absolute, they are relative to the current X and Y positions of the view.

EDIT: Also, if the view appears at it's destination for a moment before proceeding with the animation, the answer to one of my previous questions may be useful. [FragmentTransaction animation is working but appears glitchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824718/fragmenttransaction-animation-is-working-but-appears-glitchy)